# Toast message with wrong mark always positive

Tags: reactjs, toast, toastr, react-toastify

[getting correct mark with correct message i want crros mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXlbj.jpg)

for the following code i am getting same(positive sign in toast message with coreect message why so plx check it once..

```
 const navigate=useNavigate();
 const onFinish = async(values)=>{
   try {
     const response= await axios.post('/api/user/login',values);
     if(response.data.success)
     {
         toast.success(response.data.message);
         toast("Redirecting to home page.");
         localStorage.setItem("token",response.data.data);
         navigate("/");
     }
     else{
       toast.success(response.data.message);
     }
    } catch (error) {
       toast.error("something went wrong");
    }
 }
```

printing toast message

```
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});
        {
            if(!user)
            {
                return res
                .status(200)
                .send({message:"User does not exist",success:false});
            }
            const isMatach=await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password);
            //req.body.password->entered password
            //user.password->encrypted password from db
            if(!isMatach)
            {
                return res
                .status(200)
                .send({message:"Password in incorrect",success:false});
            }
            else{
                const token= jwt.sign({id:user._id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:"1d"});
                                                    //prcess varible        //validation time
                 res
                .status(200)
                .send({message:"Login successful",success:true,data:token});                                                                            
            }                               
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res
        .status(500)
        .send({message:"error in login",success:false,error});
    }
})
```

I was trying to get a taost message with, i am getting the correct message but with the wrong mark of postive every time even in negative case.

Comment: You show frontend for login but beckans for register

Comment: You send status 200 when user doesn't exist but it should be an error status e.g. 404. Same with every other error response

Comment: @Konrad what status code should I use is it 404?? whenever I am using any status code other then 200 it show the wrong message(something went wrong) with 404 to.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status